# delegate Multithreading EndInvoke?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, delegates

This method in my .aspx file...

```
   private static string GetPageAsString(string address)
        {
            AsyncWebRequester.StartRequest(address);
            TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(1000000);  // 1 second=10,000,000          
            DateTime tryToGetAnswerUntil = DateTime.Now.Add(timeout);
            string returnXML = "";
            while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnXML) && DateTime.Now < tryToGetAnswerUntil )
            {
                returnXML = AsyncWebRequester.GetResult(address);                
            }
            return returnXML;
        }
```

accesses methods in this class...

```
public class AsyncWebRequester
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, string> retrievedxml = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public static void StartRequest(string uri)
        {
            try
            {
                InitiateAsyncRequestDelegate mydelegate = new InitiateAsyncRequestDelegate(InitiateAsyncRequest);
                mydelegate.BeginInvoke(uri, null, null);
            }
            catch {}
        }      

        private delegate void InitiateAsyncRequestDelegate(string uri); 

        private static void InitiateAsyncRequest(string uri) 
        {
            WebRequest request;
            try
            {
                request = WebRequest.Create(uri);              

                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    retrievedxml.Add(uri, result);
                }
            }
            catch { }
            finally { request = null; }
        }

        public static string GetResult(string uri)
        {
            string xml = "";
            if (retrievedxml.ContainsKey(uri))
            {            
                xml = retrievedxml[uri];
                retrievedxml.Remove(uri);
            }
            return xml;              
        }

    }
```

Basically this means: fire-and-forget some threads to ask for xml from a website. If I get xml back from the site, fine; otherwise I just forget about the thread. In any case, actually, I just forget about the thread (as far as I know).

The question is: Is that ok, or should I do something to actively terminate the threads (EndInvoke()?), or does the GarbageCollector handle it for me, so I dont risk starving the memory or bringing the server to it's knees in some other way. In other words: Is my code bullet-proof?

Comment: BTW, `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)`, or `DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1)`

Comment: Your `finally` block is completely useless.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `GetPageAsString()` is still just going to block. You might as well do everything synchronously.

Comment: Your waiting code is extremely inefficient.  You should use a timed `WaitOne()` on a WaitHandle.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to call `EndInvoke()`.

In your case, you should just call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` instead; it's simpler.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Let me reply to them from the top:

Comment: * FromSeconds / addSeconds only takes integers; I need to set timeout to fractions of seconds.
* why is my finally-block useless?

Comment: * What I am trying to do: Initially, I used WebResponse synchronously, setting WebResponse.TimeOut to ½ second. Problem: TimeOut has no effect if the server from which I am trying to get a response, is offline, which means I could get to wait 15 seconds. So basically I just neeedeed some way to control the timeout, and this is what I came up with (my multithreading experience not being very long). I can live with this implementation, my main concern being the one I mentioned about memorystarvation.
* Does calling EndInvoke kill  the threads?

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question: I need to make a number of requests to "http://worldweatheronline.com?city=...", which returns time and weather as xml (which I cache on my server for 15 minutes). Sometimes worldweatheronline is down, so I don't want to make my application hang for 10 seconds or more pr. request, which it will if I execute every request synchronously, one after the other.

Comment: 1) Wrong; both `AddSeconds` and `FromSeconds` take doubles.

Comment: 2) Setting a local variable to `null` at the end of a method doesn't do any good; it's about to go out of scope anyway

Comment: 3) No; `EndInvoke()` is a blocking call.  Aborting a thread is possible, but is never a good idea.

Comment: 3. about the threads: I still am not sure whether my code starts threads that will live forever?

Comment: Your threads won't execute forever, but you will leak memory by not calling `EndInvoke`.

Comment: ok, thanks, seems like I need to do some research about EndInvoke.

Comment: using the ThreadUtil class from http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/threadpool.shtml, I think I have solved my problem: public static void StartRequest(string uri) { try { InitiateAsyncRequestDelegate mydelegate = new InitiateAsyncRequestDelegate(InitiateAsyncRequest); ThreadUtil.FireAndForget(mydelegate, uri); } catch {} }